# Add default values to decorated function and update type signature

Tags: python, decorator, typing

I'd like to create decorator which adds default values to function arguments, but preserves the argument names and types of the function signature.

```py
from typing import Callable

def optional[**P](f: Callable[P, None]) -> Callable[P, None]:
    def wrapper(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        args_with_default = ...  # fill in missing argument values
        f(**args_with_default)

    return wrapper

@optional
def my_func(a: str, b: int):
    ...

my_func("a")  # ERROR: b also expected
```

Is this possible?

Comment: This sounds pretty much sounds like what you would achieve with https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: I'm concerned with having the static type checker (e.g. mypy or pyright) understand that `my_func("a")` is valid when decorating with `@optional`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the pattern of setting default values to existing functions is typically achieved by using `functools.partial`. See the following example:

```py
from functools import partial

def f(a: int, b: int, c: int) -> int:
    return a + b + c

# set defaults for b and c
g = partial(f, b=1, c=2)

g(a=1, c="c")
```

If I check this code with pyright I get for the last line:

```
Argument of type "Literal['c']" cannot be assigned to parameter "c" of type "int" in function "__call__"
  "Literal['c']" is incompatible with "int"  (reportArgumentType)
```

Which seems the correct behavior.

I also checked with mypy and it did not complain. Possibly because of this open issue: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1484

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! But this is not quite the same, calling `f` is only possible with `partial` but not with just `f` itself.

Comment: Then I don't understand the intended behavior. When you use `f` itself, the defaults should be defined on `f`. Adding defaults to an existing function requires defining a new function. This is also what is happening with the decorator.